# IE10: style is not taken into account appropriately when replacing div content with .html()

Tags: jquery, html, windows, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have this code snippet (embedded in an angularjs app) intended to replace the content of an existing div popup.

```
    var scroller = $("#popoverImageViewer .scroller");

    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i<c.length; i++) {

        var e = c[i];
        var content = $(e).html();
        var url     = $(e).css('background-image').replace(".thumb","").replace("/thumb","/fullsize");

        console.log("scope.openPopoverImageViewer ("+p+", "+index+") url = "+url);

        var sHtml = 
        "<div style=\"background-image: "+ url +"\">\n\
            <div>\n"
                +content
            +"</div>\n\
        </div>\n";
        html += sHtml;
        console.log("scope.openPopoverImageViewer ("+p+", "+index+") html = "+sHtml);
    }

    scroller.html(html);
```

It works on all platforms except on IE10/Windows 8 which generate folders as attributes as follows:

[image]

Any idea why ?

Comment: The proper format is `url(url)`, I'm guessing IE is returning just the url while other browsers return the whole thing, you can just console log `url` to check it.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo Actually it wasn't the url( missing but extraneous double quote generated by IE. Btw, I don't understand why I can't see console logs nor an updated DOM in the F12 development tools on my IE10 which makes it had to fix things. Any idea on that by chance?

Comment: You'd have better to use relevant jQuery's methods to create DOM nodes instead of using string concatenation. Regarding IE console, doesn't it what your screenshot is actually showing?

Comment: Console: yep. But it does no more show anything beside initial HTML code (no more DOM update nor console messages). @A.Wolff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just realized that IE10 code snippet…

```
   var url = $(e).css('background-image');
```

returns url in the form of url("that_very_url"} with extraneous double quote, hence the issue afterwards, where IE10 thinks the first double quote closes the style attribute, the remaining of the url generate extraneous attribute.